# continuous, closed and surjective not open.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, retraction

[image]

Above proof, [Topology, J.Munkres (Part 2 Algebraic topology)]

I cannot show that the map $\pi: S^1\times I\to B^2$ given by $\pi(x,t)=(1-t)x$ is continuous, closed and surjective, but is not open.

Any help?

Comment: Consider a small open rectangle around $(1,1)$.

Comment: How many of those four properties can your verify?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the notation - $B^2$ is the (closed) unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$, but $(x,t)\mapsto (1-t)x$ takes real values?

Comment: @Math1000 No, $x\in S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2, t \in [0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$, so $(1-t)x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Oh right, $x\in S^1$ here. Never mind!

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text but Latex formatted text.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\{(x,y)\in S^1\,|\,y>0\}\times I$. It is an open subset of $S^1\times I$, but its image under $\pi$ is$$\{(x,y)\in B^2\,|\,y>0\}\cup\{(0,0)\},$$which is not an open subset of $B^2$. Therefore $\pi$ is not an open map. But it is closed, since it is continuous and its domain is compact.